# Limiting texture coordinate at edge of polygon

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I've written a GLSL shader to emulate a vintage arcade game's indexed color tile-based graphics. I made a couple of shaders, one that does this with point sprites, and another using polygons. The point sprite shader converts `gl_PointCoord` to a pixel coordinate within each tile like so:

```c
    vec2 pixelFloat = gl_PointCoord * tileSizeInPixels;

    ivec2 pixel = ivec2(int(pixelFloat.x), int(pixelFloat.y));

    // pixel is now used in conjunction with a tile 'ID' uniform
    // to locate indexed colors with a texture lookup from a
    // large texture representing the game's ROM, with GL_NEAREST filtering.
    // very clever
```

The polygon shader instead uses an attribute buffer to pass pixel coordinates (which range {0.0 … 32.0} for a 32-pixel square tile, for example). After conversion to `int`, each fragment within the tile sees pixel coordinate values ranging x {0 … 31} y {0 … 31}, **except**:

This worked fine apart from artefacts sometimes showing at the edge of the tile with the higher numbered pixel coordinate at certain resolutions. I guessed that would be due to the fragment being at just the right location to be right on the maximum value of either `gl_PointCoord` or the vertex attribute value of 32.0, causing that fragment to sample the wrong tile.

These artefacts went away when I clamped the pixel ivec like this:

```c
    vec2 pixelFloat = gl_PointCoord * tileSizeInPixels;

    ivec2 pixel = ivec2(
        min(int(pixelFloat.x), tileSizeInPixels - 1),
        min(int(pixelFloat.y), tileSizeInPixels - 1));
```

which solved the problem and didn't introduce any new artefacts.

My question is: Is there some way of controlling the interpolation of `gl_PointCoord` or my pixel coordinate attribute such that we can guarantee the interpolated value will range

```
   minimum value <= interpolated value < maximum value
```

as opposed to

```
   minimum value <= interpolated value <= maximum value
```

Is there some way I can avoid using `min()` here?

NB: `GL_CLAMP_*` is not an option here, as the pixel coordinate is used to look up the pixel's index color from a much larger texture, which is essentially the game's sprite ROM loaded into a single large texture buffer.

Comment: The issue on your last question was that you declared your method as static

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the question once I solved it myself as I thought there was minimal value in leaving such a trivial mistake that probably wouldn't be found by someone making the same mistake.